# selenium 1 text box autofill

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

1. I'm trying to do autofill for google search
2. Below is code i tried based on google search results and some blog entries
3. I'm only posting the code to type in text

   ```
   selenium.open("/");
   selenium.type("q", "banga");
   selenium.typeKeys("q", "lore");
   selenium.keyDown("q", "\\13");
   selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isTextPresent('bangalore')", "60000");
   ```
4. Any adivce/suggestions for this would be helpful
5. This code/approach does not autofill the search box

I'm trying it out in IE8

Comment: This does not autofill. It does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selenium.type("q", "bangalore")`
`selenium.Click(//div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/b) //selects 2nd option from the Autofill dropdown`.

For IDE. Insert this html into your source.

`<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/b</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>`

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you get this text for click.

Comment: What is the learning ? How can we figure out for other similar sites that populate text autofill.

Comment: i used firebug to check, the xpath of the contents that are displayed when you type something in the input box of google search. Install firebug in your firefox browser. Open firebug and Right-Click on the element in the page whose loactor you want to know, select "Inspect Element". Element will get highlighted in the firebug console, you can right click on it and copy the xpath/css loactor.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will open the front page, type "bangalore", click Search, then wait:

```
selenium.open("/");
selenium.type("q", "bangalore");
selenium.clickAndWait("btnG");
selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isTextPresent('bangalore')", "60000");
```

Comment: I'm trying to fill it by selecting the autofill option. Can you check it. I donot want to pass it as complete text.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean! Which browser are you using with selenium?

Comment: IE8, Apologies for not quoting it in the question.

Comment: Hmm, should be ok then. How did you get the initial selenium code? Maybe you could try using Selenium IDE to record your actions...

Comment: Not able to paste in comment section sorry.

Comment: Sorry it turns out bad, looks bad when i post the code. IDE generated code does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "select" option to select the value from auto fill?
or using "click" command on element which you want to be select in your search box?

Comment: I want to select from the drop down suggestion, Can you please post an example or correct my code

Comment: look at the html of suggestion list which is generated and then try click(elementLocator)